# How do I add older versions of code into a Subversion repository as tagged versions

Tags: svn, version-control

When we finally started using source control, old versions of code were added into the SVN in their own discrete folders, so I ended up with

```
root
\libv4
\libv4.2
\lib4.3
\lib5
```

What I would like to get to is having these older versions of the code as tagged versions inside the repository, like this:

```
root
\lib
   \tags
      \v4
      \v4.2
      \v4.3
      \v5.0
   \trunk
```

how would I go about doing this? I'm using Tortoise SVN on the client side, and visualSVN server at the back.

Comment: Do you mean by 'their own discrete folders' separate repositories? Or one repository with structure that you don't like?

Comment: It's one repository with a bad structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform a full checkout of your root directory, and create the tags\lib folder.  Perform an add using Tortoise svn, but don't commit yet.  Next, move each of the old lib folders under the new lib folder by using drag/drop with your right mouse button.  When you drop the folder you'll have the option to "move" the files there using tortoise svn.

Once all the folders are in the correct place, you can commit everything.  That way you won't lose the history on the old lib folders, and your repository is nicely restructured.